# How is 0xe+foo parsed?

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, token, literals

How is
`0xe+foo`
parsed?

I know that it is parsed as a whole preprocessing number, but i dont get why, because, how can the operator "+" be a pp-number?

```
pp-number : 
digit
. digit
pp-number digit
pp-number identifier-nondigit 
pp-number ’ digit 
pp-number ’ nondigit 
pp-number e sign
pp-number E sign
pp-number p sign
pp-number P sign
pp-number .
```

Here is no "+", so thats why i thought it is parsed as:

0xe + foo

What am I missing? I know the rule of maximum match, but how is the "+" sign a pp-number?

If I would have `x+++++y` it is parsed as `x ++ ++ + y`, which makes sense, but how is then `0xe+foo` not parsed as `0xe + foo`?

Comment: from trying it with compilers, they treat `+foo` as a suffix

Comment: The way it may be converted to a number is if `foo` has a numeric value (if it is in the compiler's symbol table as a numeric entity such as an integer or the address of a function or an array).

Comment: A '+' can indicate an operator, or a number.  To be part of a number, the `+` must be followed by integer digits or floating point digits.  If the `+` fails at being a number, then it is checked for being an operator.  The order may be modified by precedence rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` matches *sign* in the production you quoted.

Comment: Omg.. i thought it is meant like "e-sign", so just like "e". Oh man... my english not very good, and this is a beautiful example. Thanks a lot!